# `Error:osgi: [optaplanner-core] Unexpected build error` on building CloudBalancingHelloWorld

Tags: intellij-idea, optaplanner

1. I cloned [optaplanner](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner)'s repository.
2. I imported the top-level pom.xml in IntelliJ IDEA.
3. Then I tried to run `org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.app.CloudBalancingHelloWorld`.

I get the following error: `Error:osgi: [optaplanner-core] Unexpected build error`

The [doc](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.9.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#quickStart) says `the maven integration will take care of the rest`, so I guess I am missing something.

[image: Screenshot of IDEA showing the build error]

- Question 1: Can I somewhat configure IDEA (or use the CLI) to show more verbose errors, so that I can debug it? `Unexpected build error` is not enough information for me to figure that problem out.
- Question 2: How can I fix this error?

FYI, this box is running Ubuntu 18.04 (edit: exact same issue on Fedora 28). My maven version is as follows.

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-25T04:49:05+09:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.5.3
Java version: 1.8.0_181, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

EDIT: IntelliJ version: 2018.2.1

**Run configuration:**

[image: Run configuration]

Comment: Which maven version is this? Can you try again - the verions numbers recently changed and that can cause temporarily SNAPSHOT update errors.

Comment: I tried again but the same issue happens on IDEA. I included maven's version in the body of the question.

Comment: What's the IntelliJ version? I am running that on IDEA on Fedora with no issues, I 'd like to know what you're doing different.

Comment: I added the run configuration. Well I am able to run the example using `cd optaplanner-examples && mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.optaplanner.examples.cloudbalancing.app.CloudBalancingHelloWorld`.

So I guess my problem is solved. But I still cannot get it to work within IDEA.

Comment: **Yet another reason to drop OSGi support in OptaPlanner 8 :)**

Answer (score 1):

You should disable the Osmorc plugin in IDEA. After thay the project will normally build

Answer (score 0):

Intellij IDEA's OSGI plugin chould not recongnized properties like parsedVersion.*, which was generate by org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin added in parent project [org.kie:kie-parent](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-build-bootstrap/blob/2a656bff1673bc4c37a19d6abefc672e53ea8daa/pom.xml#L1740).

You should disable the OSGI plugin, or add following code to /pom.xml manually.

```
<properties>
    ...
    <parsedVersion.majorVersion>7</parsedVersion.majorVersion>
    <parsedVersion.minorVersion>28</parsedVersion.minorVersion>
    <parsedVersion.incrementalVersion>0</parsedVersion.incrementalVersion>
</properties>
```

[Drools](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools) and [jbpm](https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm) has the same issue, because they also use org.kie:kie-parent as parent project. It could be sloved by the same way.

Answer (score 0):

i meet the same problem,and solve it later.

first,remove the osgi module in  `Project Structure`->`Facets` .

then, change the `Run/Debug Configurations` as the project README.adoc said.

after all ,i can run it successfully.